# How to GET users assigned to a BIM360 project in .NET

Tags: .net, postman, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Is it possible to `GET` users that are assigned to a project? In BIM 360 I can manually assign users to a project and there are ways of doing this in .NET (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/), but how do I know which users are assigned to what projects. When getting the user's information, there is no properties related to project's that users are assigned to.

This is the information of a Source Project that currently has two users assigned to it.

```
{
    "id": "****************************",
    "account_id": "****************************",
    "name": "Sample Project",
    "start_date": "2018-11-06",
    "end_date": "2018-12-06",
    "value": null,
    "currency": null,
    "status": "active",
    "job_number": null,
    "address_line_1": null,
    "address_line_2": null,
    "city": null,
    "state_or_province": null,
    "postal_code": null,
    "country": "United States",
    "business_unit_id": null,
    "created_at": "2018-11-06T15:54:15.060Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-02-20T10:04:20.035Z",
    "project_type": "Demonstration Project",
    "timezone": null,
    "language": "en",
    "construction_type": null,
    "contract_type": null,
    "last_sign_in": "2019-02-20T10:04:18.000Z"
},`
```

And this is one of the users assigned to the project above. The only relation I can see is the `role` and `access_level`, but it doesn't specify the project that belongs to.

```
{
    "account_id": "****************************",
    "role": "project_user",
    "status": "active",
    "company_id": "****************************",
    "company_name": "Autodesk",
    "last_sign_in": null,
    "default_role": null,
    "default_role_id": null,
    "access_level": "project_user",
    "id": "****************************",
    "email": "john.smith@mail.com",
    "name": "New Member",
    "nickname": "Johnny",
    "first_name": "New",
    "last_name": "Member",
    "uid": null,
    "image_url": "http://static-dc.autodesk.net/etc/designs/v201412151200/autodesk/adsk-design/images/autodesk_header_logo_140x23.png",
    "address_line_1": "The Fifth Avenue",
    "address_line_2": "#301",
    "city": "New York",
    "postal_code": "10011",
    "state_or_province": "New York",
    "country": "United States",
    "phone": "(634)329-2353",
    "company": "Autodesk",
    "job_title": "Software Developer",
    "industry": "IT",
    "about_me": "Nothing here",
    "created_at": "2016-07-27T19:09:31.998Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-02-19T08:59:57.852Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the endpoints for that purpose is yet to be released and will be part of our BIM 360 API v2.

Rest assure that those endpoints are under internal review and not so far away. Stay tuned to our [Forge Blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog) for updates.

For now you will need to keep track of the users added with your own data persistence.